# Find the limit of the sequence $x_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{x_n}$ given that $x_0 = 1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I tried solving this recursive function using a linear combination method, but was unable to come to a conclusion. I do not know where to start finding the limit

Comment: Hint: Compute the six first terms. What do you observe?

Comment: General method, by the way: assuming the limit exists and is $x$, it satisfies $x = 1+\frac{1}{x}$ (by continuity). However, as Did says, the first thing you should always do with a sequence is to calculate the first few terms to see if you can spot a pattern.

Comment: If you don't know how to use Did's hint:

By computing the first terms of the sequence, one can note that $$x_n=\dfrac{f_{n+2}}{f_{n+1}},$$ where $f_i$ is the $i$-th term in the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) and [it is well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Limit_of_consecutive_quotients) that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}.$

Comment: FWIW, the idea in my hint is to realize that $(x_{2n})$ is increasing and $(x_{2n+1})$ is decreasing and $1\le x_{2k}<x_{2i+1}\le2$ for every $(k,i)$... and that these basic observations are awfully close to provide a full solution **without any prior familiarity with Fibonacci sequences**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ability to answer this quickly will depend on whether you're familiar with the Fibonacci numbers.

If you're not you can still use elementary methods to calculate the limit: Firstly however we need to show that the limit does indeed exist. To do this one could show its Cauchy. I did this by firstly showing by induction that: $ 3/2 \le x_n \le 2$ for all $n \ge 1$.  (I'll omit this since it was just a standard inducion, but I can add it in if you want?)

I then used the definition of Cauchy with $n \ge m \ge N$ and calculated: 
\begin{align} 
|x_n - x_m| &= \left | 1 + \frac{1}{x_{n-1}} - x_m \right | \\
& = \left |1+\frac{1}{x_{n-1}} - 1 - \frac{1}{x_{m-1}} \right| \\
& = \frac{|x_{n-1} -x_{m-1}|}{x_nx_m}
\end{align} 
Now we can iterate this procedure (assuming we are not in the trivial case of n=m) to obtain: 
\begin{align}
|x_n - x_m| &= \frac{|x_{n-m} -x_{0}|}{\prod_{i=n-m+1}^n x_i \prod_{j=1}^m x_j}\\
& = \frac{|x_{n-m} - 1|}{\prod_{i=n-m+1}^n x_i \prod_{j=1}^m x_j}\\
& = \frac{1}{\prod_{i=n-m+1}^n x_i \prod_{j=1}^m x_j}* \frac{1}{x_{n-m-1}}
\end{align}

Now using our bounds from before we deduce that:
$$|x_n - x_m| \le \left(\frac{2}{3} \right)^{m}$$
(The $\left(\frac{2}{3} \right)^{m}$ simply comes from counting the number of elements on the bottom of the final fraction and tacking a crude bound)

Which allows us to deduce $x_n$ is Cauchy. By completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ we deduce $x_n$ is convergent.

Now using our bounds we know the limit is between $3/2$ and $2$ so there is no issue with $1/x_n$ 'blowing up' so we can take the limit of both sides giving (if $x_n \rightarrow x$) that $$ x = 1 + 1/x$$ You can now solve this like a normal quadratic to find $x$. Hope this helps!

Comment: For the induction, do I simply have to prove that n=1 exists, and that n+1 also exists assuming that n exists?